# What is lim⟶ I^n M?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ is an ideal of $R$, $M$ is an $R$-module. 
$$IM\supset I^2M\supset I^3M\supset\cdots$$
What is $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\begin{subarray}{c} 
   \longrightarrow  \\ 
\end{subarray}}I^nM$ ?

Comment: A direct limit whose index set has a maximal element is just the object corresponding to the maximal element. In your case, just $IM$.

Comment: Is that right? I also thought that, but i am not sure.

Comment: If you want to be sure, just apply the definition (for any $R$ module $N$ and for any collection of homomorphisms $f_n:I_n:M\to N$ such that...&c, there exists a unique...&c...namely $f_1$). Note: the notations for direct and inverse limits refers graphically to sequences or diagrams, whose arrows point from left to right. Are you sure what you want is not the inverse (projective) limit, i.e. in this case, the intersection of the family? 

Comment: I want direct limit not inverse limit. Thanks.

Comment: What are the arrows in your direct limit?  You haven't specified any maps from $I^n M$ to $I^{n+1}M$.  Without maps, the question is meaningless.

Comment: Let $x\in I$ then $\varphi_n: I^nM\to I^{n+1}M$ defined $a\mapsto xa$

Comment: In that case, the answer depends strongly on your choice of $x$.  For example, if $x=0 \in I$ or is nilpotent, then the direct limit is the zero module.  If $x$ is idempotent in $I$, then the direct limit is $IM$.

Comment: If $x$ be an $M$-regular element in $I$ then the direct limit is $IM$?

Comment: Correction: if $x$ is idempotent, then the direct limit is $xRM$.

Comment: @minhtringuyen the mathoverflow bot just bumped this question to the front page, even though it's been answered correctly below. I think you should accept the answer below so that this question doesn't keep coming back to the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll interpret this question by agglomerating information given in the comments: We choose an element $x \in I$, and want to know the structure of the direct limit of $\{ I^nM\}_{n \geq 0}$, when the maps $I^nM \to I^{n+1}M$ are given by multiplication by $x$.

I think the answer is that we can't say very much at all in general without somewhat more information, and the assumption that $x$ is $M$-regular is not enough.  For example, if $R = \mathbf{Q}[t]$ and $M=R$, then choosing $x = t$ yields a direct limit that is the zero module, while choosing $x=1$ yields a direct limit that is $M$ (which is $IM$ in this case).  For more general rings $R$, you can get intermediate results by setting $x$ to be something that has an interesting fixed subspace, e.g., an idempotent.